# Loading Content On New View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

In my main view controller i have code that will take u to another page once the camera identifies something and you tap on the screen:

```
@objc func screenTapped(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print ("go to page for \(identifierLabel.text)")
    if currentIdentifier == "Morel"{
        let newVc = MorelViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(newVc, animated: 
true)
    }
```

in my new view controller, i have code for a table view of information:

```
 struct CellData {
    let image: UIImage?
    let contentTitle: String?
    let content: String?
   } 

import UIKit

class MorelViewController: UITableViewController {

var nature = [CellData]()
var consumption = [CellData]()
var sensory = [CellData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    menuBar.tableView = tableView

    self.navigationItem.title = "Morel Mushroom"
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    titleLabel.text = "Morel Mushroom"
    titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel

nature = [CellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Asset 1"), 
contentTitle: "WHERE TO FIND", content: "You'll find edible morel in 
rich soil that's full of nutrients—in parks, gardens, and open 
deciduous forests. They can also pop up in cemeteries and ramparts, 
often where wood chips have been laid down. They're a relatively rare 
find, so keep an eye on the forest floor."), CellData.init(image: 
#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Asset 1-1"), contentTitle: "WHEN TO 
FIND", content: "Morels are one of the first great edible mushrooms of 
spring. They usually fruit in April and May, but can linger into 
June."), CellData.init(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Asset 1- 
2"), contentTitle: "FORAGING GUIDELINES", content: "Only pick morels 
that have firm, springy flesh and nice, white stems. By the end of 
their season, morels tend to be infested with larvae, beetles, and 
other small creatures, but unwelcome guests may be hiding in their 
intricate surface and hollow interior regardless of when they’re 
picked. Be thorough, then, when brushing and washing them—but also be 
careful not to oversoak them as morels are extremely porous. Harvest 
the mushroom by carefully twisting it loose or cutting it at its base. 
Check the cut to see if the mushroom is infested with vermin and if 
the flesh is even.")] 

...
```

when the object is identified and im switching to the new view controller, im presented with this error after the nature section:

```
 Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102ffc304)
```

**Error Image Link**

[image: Screen shot]

I have no breakpoints set, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that one of these names is wrong:

```
image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Asset 1") // or one of the others
```

There are no image literals any more, so the only way to form these is by hand, which can result in an incoherent situation. I would suggest replacing them all with `UIImage(named:)`, like this:

```
image: UIImage(named: "Asset 1") // and so on
```

You might wind up with a `nil` image if a name is wrong, but at least you won't crash on that line.

Comment: i solved it before i read this, but that was exactly my problem. Thank you!